# Is there a possiblity to replace profile image gravatar with custom user images

Tags: customization, images, profiles

Is there any possibility to replace gravatar session in profile page with an custom image with their image. Which can be uploaded from their PC while creation of the account is is possible to do with coding in wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use ACF Pro to achieve that

First create a field for user image (here: tsm_local_avatar)

then filter the get_gravatar function:

```
<?php
/**
 * Use ACF image field as avatar
 * @author Mike Hemberger
 * @link http://thestizmedia.com/acf-pro-simple-local-avatars/
 * @uses ACF Pro image field (tested return value set as Array )
 */
add_filter('get_avatar', 'tsm_acf_profile_avatar', 10, 5);
function tsm_acf_profile_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {
    $user = '';

    // Get user by id or email
    if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {
        $id   = (int) $id_or_email;
        $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
    } elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ) {
            $id   = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
            $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
        }
    } else {
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );
    }
    if ( ! $user ) {
        return $avatar;
    }
    // Get the user id
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    // Get the file id
    $image_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'tsm_local_avatar', true); // CHANGE TO YOUR FIELD NAME
    // Bail if we don't have a local avatar
    if ( ! $image_id ) {
        return $avatar;
    }
    // Get the file size
    $image_url  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' ); // Set image size by name
    // Get the file url
    $avatar_url = $image_url[0];
    // Get the img markup
    $avatar = '<img alt="' . $alt . '" src="' . $avatar_url . '" class="avatar avatar-' . $size . '" height="' . $size . '" width="' . $size . '"/>';
    // Return our new avatar
    return $avatar;
}
```

More info here:
https://thestizmedia.com/acf-pro-simple-local-avatars/

Comment: In this you need to install ACF Plugin right ?

Comment: Works right out of the box. Thank you [@ZecKa](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/82323/zecka)!